# How to get sets of location from 100 km away from coastlines in python

Tags: python, cartopy, typhoon

I have a typhoon data(for 30 years, txt file) which includes the location of each typhoon(latitude, longitude), pressure, and the time each typhoon was recorded.

The data is like this.

```
1946  265 01                     
1946   3  27   0   1   12.00  153.30   45.00    0.00
1946   3  27   1   1   12.08  153.17   46.67    0.00
1946   3  27   2   1   12.17  153.03   48.33    0.00
1946   3  27   3   1   12.25  152.90   50.00    0.00
1946   3  27   4   1   12.33  152.77   51.67    0.00
1946   3  27   5   1   12.42  152.63   53.33    0.00
1946   3  27   6   1   12.50  152.50   55.00    0.00
1946   3  27   7   1   12.50  152.42   57.50    0.00
```

The header line has information of one typhoon. And after this data, I can see another header line which indicates the information of another new typhoon has started showing. (I mean this txt file has different typhoons' data.)

And I would like to get the typhoon information after the typhoon entered the locations of points of 100 km away from coastline. (This means the typhoon landfalled in a country.) How can I distinguish landfalled typhoons and not ones in python?

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709468/wrong-points-buffer-using-geopandas/74783942#74783942